# problem when Creating a web app with Azure command-line interface?

Tags: azure

I am newbie with microsoft azure and trying to study and follow the tutorial.

But my problem is, here is my tutorial :

```
# generate a unique name and store as a shell variable
webappname=mywebapp$RANDOM
# create a resource group
az group create --location westeurope --name myResourceGroup
# create an App Service plan
az appservice plan create --name $webappname --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku FREE
# create a Web App
az webapp create --name $webappname `
--resource-group myResourceGroup `
--plan $webappname
```

And my problem is, when I coded the code `az group create --location westeurope --name myResourceGroup`, it always said to me that I must login to azure but I login to azure before that.

And when I searched how to create a web app with azure CLI online, it show me a very different version command like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qILUM6DyruM

Could you please give me some advise for this problem ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: the error that I have is, for example, when I ran the 2 command

az group create --location westeurope --name myResourceGroup

it show me this error : Please run 'az login' to setup account.

Comment: ok and when you login to azure with `az login` it works fine? are you able to do `az account show` to confirm you see the right context?

Comment: when I ran the command az account show it still said to me Please run 'az login' to setup account

Comment: And what happens when you do az login? Can you show it step by step with screenshots, in your question? Please mask any sensitive content.